# FFMpeg printing "Option pixel_format not found" when using "pix_fmt"

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to do a relatively simple task - convert a video from one pixel format to another by re-encoding. This is my current command:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -pix_fmt yuv444p -i "%1" video.mp4
```

Where `%1` is the filename. However, strangely enough, ffmpeg prints out this:

```
Option pixel_format not found.
```

It's in red, so it's an error. Adding `-loglevel verbose` does not give any more information. I'm really confused about this - I did not define any "pixel_format" option. This issue occurs both when calling this command from a batch file and directly from a `cmd.exe` instance.

Replacing "`pix_fmt`" with "`pixel_format`" and putting `pix_fmt` after `-i` does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read the input file forcibly with `yuv444p`. Try

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -i "%1" -pix_fmt yuv444p video.mp4
```

The h264 *decoder* does not support user-specified pixel format thus the error: `Option pixel_format not found.` The default h264 encoder (`libx264`) on the other hand allows `-pix_fmt` option to specify the output pixel format.

Comment: `ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -i "%1" -pix_fmt yuv444p video.mp4` worked, thank you so much!

Comment: yep, forgot to delete the latter `-i "%1"` in my post. fixed.

Comment: so it is a matter of writing `-i "%1"` before `-pix_fmt`? is it like how in coding the first line is executed before going to the next? I thought these were parameters for ffmpeg?

Comment: Read the ffmpeg documentation. To the left of the `-i` argument are the input options and all after are output options.